# Generate a graph from function on the vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a concrete function $f:V\rightarrow P(V)$ that describes the neighborhood of a vertex $g$. I tried to use `FunctionalGraph[f, V]` , but apparently, this function was removed from Mathematica.

So, how to generate a graph from a function?

Comment: You have to load the Combinatorica package with ``Needs["Combinatorica`"]`` before you can use `FunctionalGraph`.

Comment: `Graph[(# <-> f[#]) & /@ v]`, where `f` is your function and `v` are the vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is something like the code

```
ClearAll[f, V, a, b, c, d]; V = {a, b, c, d};
f[a] = {b}; f[b] = {c}; f[c] = {a, d}; f[d] = {c};
Graph[Flatten[Function[x, x -> # & /@ f[x]] /@ V]]
```

which returns a directed graph. A variant is to replace the last line with

```
Graph[Flatten[(Thread[# -> f[#]]) & /@ V]]
```

and there are probably a few other ways to do it.

Comment: My graph is directed, and the function returns a set of neighbors of a certain vertex.

Comment: @user2679290 Oops! I did not notice that detail. I adjusted my code to work in that case. Thanks for telling.

Comment: Yeh, Thread is essentially what I do in a seperate function

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) with `MemberQ[f@#, #2]&` as the first argument:

Using Somos's example:

```
vl = {a, b, c, d};
f[a] = {b}; f[b] = {c}; f[c] = {a, d}; f[d] = {c};
RelationGraph[MemberQ[f @ #, #2]&, vl]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code is

```
JJ[a_]:=Map[(a->#)&,f[a]]
j=Graph[Flatten[JJ  /@V]]
```

As the code suggested by @user6014 ignores the nested sets